# How sync work using git-flow

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I and my co-worker are working to a project.
There is a `--bare` remote repo from which we have cloned to our pc.
Then we have both initialized own personal repos with git-flow.
Now I have develop and master branch.

**Which branch shoult I use to sync my work with my co-worker?**

If I not always commit all my changes in feature branches, my develop branch is dirty and I can't push it to sync.
The alternative that we use is create a new feature branch called *"sync release"* every time I want sync my work. Then the closure of the feature branch update the master branch and I can sync it (not the dirty develop branch).

This is our current workflow. What is the correct  git structure when all developer use git-flow and want share the work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing the `develop` branch is probably the best approach as it shields you away from unfinished features your co-worker is still working on.

If your local `develop` branch is dirty at any given moment, [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) can help you to save away you local work temporarily (and use `git stash pop` to take it out again after the sync).

Having said that, bear in my the git is a distributed system and, as such, you can both sync and work on a `feature` in progress without going through the “central” repo.

See for example the description in nvie’s original description of git-flow [“Decentralized but centralized”](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#decentralized-but-centralized):

[image: nvie’s “Decentralized but centralized” illustration]